# How can I convert to short form of months instead of full names?

Tags: r

I have this time dataframe

```
3/31/2001 8:15
4/31/2001 8:25
2/31/2001 8:45
4/31/2001 8:55
```

Which I am converting into months in a different column using this line of code

```
all$month<-strftime(as.Date(all$time, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%B")
```

The result I get is of the form:

```
March
April
February
April
```

But I would like to get only the short form of the month names, i.e.

```
Mar
Apr
Feb
Apr
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: `2/31/2001`??  I don't think that ever happened

Comment: I just put random numbers for illustration. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lowercase "b":

```
> strftime(as.Date("3/31/2001 8:15", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%b")
[1] "Mar"
```